# how to fixe the grid view horizontal and make the listview scrollable horizontale?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I have a horizontal gridview inside listview how making the list view scrollable horizontal  to the end

Comment: This is called as **Nested RecyclerView**. You can find many examples to understand the Nested RecyclerView. [Link1](https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047), [Link2](https://github.com/navi25/nestedRecycler)

Comment: i would scroll all the items off list view like a matrix